# What input does the external terraform datasource expect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This command returns json: `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxx`

But terraform complains:

```
data "external" "sdfsdfsdf" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", "aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxx"]
}
# error
Error: command "bash" produced invalid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use terraform [aws_instance data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance) which gives equivalent info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12249

I needed to flatten the json passed to the datasource to have 1 level of keys.